# Tooling API: Unable to update existing GlobalPicklist

Tags: tooling-api

**I'm able to create a global picklist -'Fruits'**

```
 String fieldDef = '{"Metadata":{"customValue":[{"label":"Apple","valueName":"Apple"},{"label":"Orange","valueName":"Orange"}],"description":null,"masterLabel":"Fruits","sorted":false,"urls":null},"FullName":"Fruits"}';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(fieldDef);
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');      req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/sobjects/GlobalValueSet');
req.setMethod('POST');
Http httpreq = new Http();
HttpResponse res  = httpreq.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

**Now I'm trying to update the 'Fruits' global picklist values. Apple->Grape, Orange->Strawberry**

```
String configType = 'Fruits';
String fieldDef = '{"Metadata":{"customValue":[{"label":"Apple","valueName":"Grape"},{"label":"Orange","valueName":"Strawberry"}],"description":null,"masterLabel":"'+configType+'","sorted":false,"urls":null},"FullName":"'+configType+'"}';
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setBody(fieldDef);
req.setHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + UserInfo.getSessionID());
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
req.setEndpoint(URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()+
   '/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query/?q=select+id+from+globalvalueset+where+MasterLabel=\''+
   configType+'\'+limit+1?_HttpMethod=PATCH');
req.setMethod('POST');
Http httpreq = new Http();
HttpResponse res  = httpreq.send(req);
system.debug(res.getBody());
```

**But I'm receiving this error -- [{"errorCode":"METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED","message":"HTTP Method 'POST' not allowed. Allowed are HEAD,GET"}]**

Comment: I'd expect that the query resource isn't one to be used for updating data, so your error shouldn't really be that much of a surprise. I'm not familiar enough with the tooling API to be able to answer this question, but I'd imagine that the right API resource to use would be contained somewhere in the documentation for the Tooling API.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be sending a `PATCH` request here `req.setEndpoint('....?_HttpMethod=PATCH');` then setting the method as `POST` `req.setMethod('POST');` whereas you actually want to perform a `GET` request here as you are trying to retrieve results based on a query.

Your request should be modified as:

```
req.setEndpoint(
    URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().toExternalForm()
    +'/services/data/v41.0/tooling/query/?q=select+id+from+globalvalueset+where+MasterLabel=\''+configType
    +'\'+limit+1'); // remove the PATCH request parameter from here

req.setMethod('GET'); // change this to GET
```

If you want to update a particular record, then you should be using `PATCH` here along with the `Id` of the record to be updated.

Comment: I'm trying to update the record which has ID there. That's why i put it as PATCH along with the ID. If you look at the link above i referenced above, I already created a global picklist, and now trying to update one of the existing record.

Comment: But your code does not reflect that. You should edit your question then to reflect what exactly are you passing to update the record. In its current form, you are just querying and it should be a `GET` request.

Comment: I edited my question to reflect my entire question. thanks Jayant Das

Comment: You still ate **not** updating a record but only querying it. I will recommend to take a look at REST API docs [related to updates](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_update_fields.htm)

Comment: I got what you are saying. Basically i cannot combine to fetch Id and update values in one call. Need to make an API call to fetch the Id first using GET, and by using that Id make a POST. Thanks again!

Comment: That's exactly what you need.